# Error en manejo de operador logico OR - python

Tags: python

tengo un problema, estoy iniciando en python y me encontre con este error, se supone que en el `if` si pongo uno que no sea "explora" o "telcel" deberia mandarme al `else`, sin embargo, cuando pongo "toks" me sigue mandando al `print("Welcome, you can print by a charge to you account\n")`.

¿alguien me puede orientar de cual es mi error y como arreglarlo?

muchas gracias

```
print("Welcome to the print access system.\n")
company = input(print("Please type the company you work for:\nExplora\nTelcel\nToks")).lower()

if company == "explora" or "telcel":
     print("Welcome, you can print by a charge to you account\n")
else:
  print("You can print only at night.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("Welcome to the print access system.\n")
company = input("Please type the company you work for:\nExplora\nTelcel\nToks\n").lower()

if (company == "explora") or (company == "telcel"):
    print("Welcome, you can print by a charge to you account\n")
else:
    print("You can print only at night.")
```

Comment: Te agradezco el apoyo, ya quedo...

Comment: Para eso estamos ;)

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que cuando pones `company == "explora" or "telcel"`, no estás comparando si `copany` también puede tener el valor de `'telcel'`, las comparaciones no funciona así. Lo que el compilador ve, es equivalente a esto:

```
if (company == "explora") or "telcel"
```

La primera es una comparación que dará *verdadero* solo si `company` tiene el valor `'explora'`, pero la segunda siempre dará verdadero, pues en python, una expresión constante o variable puede evaluarse como booleana para saber si tiene algún valor.

Lo correcto, es volver a comparar la variable, así:

```
if (company == "explora") or (company == "telcel")
```

Aunque los paréntesis no son necesarios, los dejé para darle claridad a la expresión.

Volviendo a la evaluación de `"telcel"` por si solo, esta característica del lenguaje nos permite saber de manera rápida si una variable tiene algún valor, pues es posible hacer algo como:

```
miVariable = None
# mas código aquí que podría o no asignarle un valor a miVariable
if (miVariable)
  print("si tiene valor")
```

En este caso, la expresion `miVariable`, sola, sin ninguna comparación, devuelve verdadero cuando `miVariable` es distinto de `None` y falso cuando es igual.

Comment: excelente... !! te agradezco